# Unable to post request successfully when I select raw json on Postman

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, postman

I'm getting a bad request from postman when I make a request using *raw json* on Postman. The `POST` request accepts the following payload:

`{"BusinessID": 34222222}`

When I select form-data the request is successful.
I also copied the Python code from postman and executed it but I get a bad request.

**Screenshot**
[image]

The same applies when I try to run the code below.

```
query=99858585
url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.io/permit/api/checkBusiness"

payload = "{\"BusinessID\": query}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "1bda2a65-6ed4-45d2-8029-5e70efa336ec,c1a967af-856e-4ab0-ad88-83b0b5c496df",
    'Host': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.io",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "23",
    'Cookie': "ci_session=hnv0nsiksienscujctqmdm5mp2b0dp4q",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

**When I select form-data the request is successful**

[image]

**Headers after selecting form-data***

[image]

Comment: In the first image, you have the type as 'text' but that looks like you're sending 'JSON', can you check that and make sure the request header is set. As you haven't added any implementation details, no one will be able to know what that endpoint accepts. What format does BusinessID need to be sent in?